# Neo4J: adding number rankings to an ordered output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say that there is the following query:

```
MATCH(r: Restaurant)
WITH r.restaurantName AS `Restaurant name`, r.restaurantFoodRating AS `Restaurant food rating`
ORDER BY `Restaurant food rating` DESC
RETURN `Restaurant name`, `Restaurant food rating`
```

It returns the following:

Row 1 `"Fat Bob's", 10`

Row 2 `"Slim Jim's", 9.8`

Row 3 `"Quick Rick's", 8.7`

I want my output to have a number based on the ranking of the restaurant. The highest rated restaurant is Fat Bob's, so it should have a rank of 1.

Desired output:

Row 1 `"Fat Bob's", 10, 1`

Row 2 `"Slim Jim's", 9.8, 2`

Row 3 `"Quick Rick's", 8.7, 3`

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COLLECT` and `UNWIND` to implement the same.

```
MATCH(r: Restaurant)
WITH r ORDER BY r.restaurantFoodRating DESC
WITH COLLECT(r) as rs
UNWIND range(1, size(rs)) as rank
WITH rs[rank-1] AS r, rank
RETURN r.restaurantName AS `Restaurant name`, r.restaurantFoodRating AS `Restaurant food rating`, rank
```

Here we have ordered restaurants using `WITH`, `COLLECT` will create a ordered list. `UNWIND` will loop on a range 1 to the size of the list, you can use this index to get restaurant node from the list by order and return the same with restaurant details.